# Using a input function to calculate alpha from a input

Tags: python

I am very new to programming, I am trying to code a function that prints the variance and mean based on a alpha I type in, or if I am not typing anything it defaults to 1.96. When I don't type anything it works fine, but when I type for example 1.625, it returns "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'"

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

def estimat(data):
    var = np.var(data, ddof = 1)
    forv = np.mean(data)
    z = a*np.sqrt(var/len(data))
    konf = {forv+z,forv-z}
    return {"varians": var, "forventning,":forv, "konfidensintervall":konf}

x = stats.norm.rvs(0,1,100)

a = input("Enter your alpha:  ") or 1.96
print (estimat(x))
```

Comment: `a = float(input("Enter your alpha:  "))`, otherwise it's trying to multiply by `"1.625"` (a string).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there but had to change how your alpha is entered a little bit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

def estimat(data):
    var = np.var(data, ddof = 1)
    forv = np.mean(data)
    z = float(a)*np.sqrt(var/len(data))
    konf = {forv+z,forv-z}
    return {"varians": var, "forventning,":forv, "konfidensintervall":konf}

x = stats.norm.rvs(0,1,100)

print("Enter your alpha:  ")
a = input()
if(a == ''):
    a = 1.96

print (estimat(x))
# print (a)
```

The text should not be inside an `input()` so I placed above it with a `print()`.

The `# print(a)` was there to check if the right entered/automated number was taken, I left it in the code so you can always check what happens if you alter your code.

**edit**
@Ignatius Reilly comment under the uestion is cleaner and more efficient

Comment: My suggestion in comments is cleaner for reading numbers, but it will raise an error if the input is empty. Your solution can deal with both numbers and empty input.